# CSS nth ul li properties

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` `li` set up as 2 buttons. The page has 4 sections and the buttons are inside each section.

What I am trying to achieve is that in the 1st section the 2 buttons float right and in the 2nd section the 2 buttons float left and so on. When I set it up as `:nth-child(odd)` it separates up the 2 li elements so it sends one button left and the other right.

I understand that it is working but I was wondering if there was a way to set it up so it takes the 2 buttons as a pair and sends one set right and then left and so on.

```css
li:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "dinnextltpro";
  height: 25px;
  left: 25.5%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  top: -52px;
  width: 125px;
}

li{
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "dinnextltpro";
  height: 25px;
  left: 55.5%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  top: -52px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs1">WHAT'S IN THE BAG</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs3">PLAYER HISTORY</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show a more clear example of the HTML structure for both button sections and the CSS you have tried. I am not sure what the CSS included has to do with the buttons, except to guess its what you tried for the float right ones.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on here because your CSS doesn't correspond to the HTML you are showing here.  Sounds like you might want to just mark up your content more accurately rather than ask CSS to do all the work.

Comment: Basically this page is a template and the 4 different sections loads the template and displays the content. There aren't four separate ul li codes for the buttons, just the one a will automatically display it when the template is being called. This is running on Wordpress. Sorry if it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ul:nth-child(odd) li {
    ...
}
```

In this way you select the section(unordered list) with nth-child and than select the li inside.

Comment: This does not work because the code I put up there was just a portion of the entire code for the page. The code I am using is a template for a wordpress page. There is only one <ul> being used in the template but is being displayed 4 times through out the page because the template is being called 4 times. One for each section.

Comment: You could try to set it two times like nth-child(3n) and nth-child(4n). In this way every third and every fourth li can be selected.